# how to create collection programatically in mongodb using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a collection in MongoDB programmatically but I do not know how to create it. I have one common model for schema, Using this how to create collection many collections with a different name. If anyone knows please help.

common.model.js:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 var userSchemaOil = new mongoose.Schema({

    pid: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    weight: {
        type: String
    },
    price: {
        type: Number
    }  

});
```

create.controller.js:

```
 module.exports.createCollection = (req, res, next) => {

    let collectionName=req.query.collectionname; //Example: Tea

    module.exports = mongoose.model( collectionName, userSchemaOil);

   ?

    }
```

Comment: You may want to refer https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#models  
this is as simple as follows   
 let Tea= mongoose.model('Tea', userSchemaOil);
 let brand=  mongoose.model('Brand', userSchemaOil);

Comment: @VipulPatil: How to create a collection in mongodb?

Comment: The first time you save a document, the collection will be created.

Comment: @Pappa S  As Joe mentioned, the first interaction with MongoDB will create the collection. Moreover,  on npm start  empty collection will be created.